# Get columns to autocomplete in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to do this?

When I start writing `SELECT [` I'd like the columns that are available to pop up so I can choose from them.

Currently, to know the columns I'm doing a `SELECT *` in another query. It takes a very long time to navigate through Object Explorer and find my table + expand the columns, too.

No IntelliSense options show up for me either to configure this.

Comment: Enable "intelli"sense, and make sure you're qualifying your columns. That's basic functionality of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the table name, type in:

```
select * from [your tablename]
```

After that, highlight the table name, then press Alt + F1 on your keyboard.

You will then be prompted all the column names of the table.

Select all the columns you require, then press Ctrl + C on your keyboard.

Remove the "*" from your select and paste the column names.

You then just need to add the commas in front / the back, depending on your preference.

Hope this helps.